# file.write with Python receive error message connectionClosed

Tags: python

I have working Python script that I am trying to modify.  The script gets prices for stocks and prints them out in the Python console.  I am trying to change this to write the prices to a text file.   Here is the original code:

class BerryWrapper(EWrapper):

```
def __init__(self):

    pass

def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):

    if (field == 4):

        print 'Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

    elif (field == 1):

        print 'Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

    elif (field == 2):

        print 'Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
```

This seems to work fine.  I modified it with these changes to read:

class BerryWrapper(EWrapper):

```
def __init__(self):

    pass

with open('log_me.txt','w') as file:

    def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):

        if (field == 4):

            print 'Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))

        elif (field == 1):

            print 'Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))

        elif (field == 2):

            print 'Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))
```

When I ran this, I received the following message:

id:I/O operation on closed file

connectionClosed

What I am not sure about is the timing.  I want to open the file once and then let it remain open while all these prices come and and get written.  Do you know what I need to do?

Comment: Consider using the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order for

```
with open('log_me.txt','w') as file:

    def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):
```

as

```
def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):
    with open('log_me.txt','w') as file:
```

But you should care that `w` flag in `open` will re-write your file on each call of `tickPrice`. You can omit this behavior by using flag `a` that will [append data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) to file.

Comment: Thanks!  Do I need to open the file once for writing - and then later for appending?  Or can I just use the 'a' flag and it will open the first time for writing and later appending?

Comment: @user3229570 yes opening with `a` will create also create the file